# Immediately replying to own questions

Tags: support

I just noticed [one user](https://superuser.com/users/168323/mcqwerty) keeping to [post questions](https://superuser.com/questions/494762/what-are-some-useful-windows-key-shortcut-keys-for-windows-8) [and then](https://superuser.com/questions/494738/why-cant-i-snap-or-dock-two-windows-8-apps-side-by-side-on-my-19-monitor) [immediately answering](https://superuser.com/questions/494889/can-i-use-a-windows-8-picture-password-on-a-non-touchscreen-device) them.

I don't think this is against any rule per se, but I'm not entirely sure if this kind of q/a is actually good?

Comment: As long as they work under the existing rules, they are acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is allowed and in fact encouraged. See [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) for more details.

Comment: So long as they're not turds

Comment: good to know, thanks!